# Copy object reference to another observable

Tags: knockout.js

In my ViewModel, **main.PlansOptions** is an array of **Plans** which is being correctly initialized with 3 Plan objects. When the user clicks a button, I would like to copy a reference of the selected plan to the **main.SelectedPlan** observable.

The problem is that, on the **ChoosePlan** function, right after I copy the selectedplan to main.SelectedPlan, the boolean values of the Plan object (**UnlimitedFences** and **ShowAdvertisings**) *lose their original values (from false to true)*.

I've tried to make main.SelectedPlan a computed and get the selected plan with an index called main.SelectedPlanIndex but the same error ocurred. I believe there's a proper way on how to copy a object (with observable properties) to another observable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

---

Definition of Plan

```
function Plan(id, name, monitors, commands, historydays, unlimitedfences, supporttype, showadvertisings) {
    var o = this;

    o.PlanId = ko.observable(id);
    o.Name = ko.observable(name);
    o.Monitors = ko.observable(monitors);
    o.Commands = ko.observable(commands);
    o.HistoryDays = ko.observable(historydays);
    o.UnlimitedFences = ko.observable(unlimitedfences); // boolean
    o.SupportType = ko.observable(supporttype);
    o.ShowAdvertisings = ko.observable(showadvertisings); // boolean
};
```

View Model

```
function PurchasePlanViewModel() {

    var main = this;

    main.PlansOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
    main.SelectedPlanIndex = ko.observable(-1);
    main.SelectedPlan = ko.observable();

    ...

    // Sub View Model (inside of PurchasePlanViewModel)
    main.SelectPlan = new function () {
        var o = this;

        o.ChoosePlan = function (selectedplan) {
            // the problem occurs here -- booleans of selectedplan are set to true
            main.SelectedPlan(selectedplan);
        }

       ...
    }
```

HTML

```
<section class="select-plan" data-bind="with: SelectPlan, visible: ShowSelectPlan">
    <div class="plans-options hidden-xs clearfix" data-bind="foreach: $root.PlansOptions">
        <div class="plan-option col-sm-4" data-bind="css: { selected : $root.SelectedPlan() ? PlanId() == $root.SelectedPlan().PlanId() : false }">
            <h4 class="plan-title" data-bind="text: Name"></h4>
            <div class="plan-info">
                <div class="vehicular-price">
                    <span class="price" data-bind="text: VehicularTrackerUnitCost.AsCurrency()"></span>

             ...

             <div class="purchase">
                 <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" data-bind="click: $parent.ChoosePlan" style="margin-top: 10px;">Quero o <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></button>
             </div>
         </div><!-- end of plan-info -->
     </div><!-- end of plan-option -->
 </div><!-- end of plans-options -->
```

Comment: Can you create simple JSFiddle demo with problem?

Comment: Is the original `Plan` in `PlansOptions` changes as well?

Comment: Yes, when o.ChoosePlan is called and main.SelectedPlan() is initialized with selectplan, the values for UnlimitedFences  and ShowAdvertisings (of selectedplan) change from false to true in the PlansOptions() observable array

Comment: You need to give more context or a minimal, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem before you are likely to get an answer. As @Ilya suggested, a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo would help people answer your question. Not sure why you have `ChoosePlan` nested inside `SelectPlan`, but with the `...` in your code it's hard to see how it's supposed to all fit together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copied `Plan` from `Plans` to `SelectedPlan`, and then you changed `UnlimitedFences` and `ShowAdvertisings` in original object.
It is fully correct that `UnlimitedFences` and `ShowAdvertisings` are changed in both objects!
I think your model is incorrect. I can propose another model:

```
function Plan(id, name, monitors, commands, historydays, unlimitedfences, supporttype, showadvertisings) {
    var o = this;

    o.PlanId = ko.observable(id);
    o.Name = ko.observable(name);
    o.Monitors = ko.observable(monitors);
    o.Commands = ko.observable(commands);
    o.HistoryDays = ko.observable(historydays);
    o.SupportType = ko.observable(supporttype);

};

function PlanHolder(plan, unlimitedfences, showadvertisings)
{
    var o = this;
    o.UnlimitedFences = ko.observable(unlimitedfences); // boolean
    o.ShowAdvertisings = ko.observable(showadvertisings); // boolean
    o.Plan = plan;
    o.clone = function()
    {
        return new PlanHolder(o.Plan, o.UnlimitedFences(), o.ShowAdvertisings());
    }
}
```

Now, you should save `observableArray` of `PlanHolder`s instead of `Plan`. And you should clone `PlanHolder` before coping it to `SelectedPlan`

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fewxjL2r) with your model. `unlimitedfences` is changed to `true` after selecting in both objects
[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fewxjL2r/1/) with `PlanHolder`. `unlimitedfences` is changed to `true` only in original object